# getting variable declarations

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

i created a parser of ASTParser type for a compilationunit. I want to use this parser to list all the variable declarations in the functions present in this particular compilationunit.Should i use ASTVisitor? if so how or is there any other way? help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try following [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.jdt/msg20735.html)

you should have a look at [`org.eclipse.jdt.core`](http://kickjava.com/src/org.eclipse.jdt.core.index.htm) plugin and specially [**`ASTParser`**](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/ASTParser.java.htm) class there.
Just to launch the parser, the following code would be enough:

```
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT); // you tell parser, that source is whole java file. parser can also process single statements
parser.setSource(source);
CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null); // CompilationUnit here is of type org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit  
// source is either char array, like this:

public class A { int i = 9; int j; }".toCharArray()

//org.eclipse.jdt.core.ICompilationUnit type, which represents java source files
```

in workspace.

> after the AST is built, you can traverse it with visitor, that extends `ASTVisitor`, like this:

```
cu.accept(new ASTVisitor() {
  public boolean visit(SimpleName node) {
    System.out.println(node); // print all simple names in compilation unit. in our example it would be A, i, j (class name, and then variables)
    return true;
  }
});
```

More details and code sample in [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.jdt/msg17244.html)

```
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
parser.setSource(compilationUnit);
parser.setSourceRange(method.getSourceRange().getOffset(), method.getSourceRange().getLength());
parser.setResolveBindings(true);
CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit)parser.createAST(null);
cu.accept(new ASTMethodVisitor());
```